# How render a HtmlTable that came from a Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have an helper that returns an htmlTable for view. The code:

```
public static HtmlTable Sales(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {
            HtmlTable tabela = new HtmlTable();
            HtmlTableRow rowHeader = new HtmlTableRow();
            HtmlTableCell cellCode = new HtmlTableCell();
            HtmlTableCell cellUnd = new HtmlTableCell();
            HtmlTableCell cellDescription = new HtmlTableCell();
            HtmlTableCell cellQtd = new HtmlTableCell();

            tabela.Width = "800px";

            cellCode.InnerText = "Código";
            cellUnd.InnerText = "Unidade";
            cellDescription.InnerText = "Descrição";
            cellQtd.InnerText = "QTD";


            cellCode.Focus();

            rowHeader.Cells.Add(cellCode);
            rowHeader.Cells.Add(cellUnd);
            rowHeader.Cells.Add(cellDescription);
            rowHeader.Cells.Add(cellQtd);

            tabela.Rows.Add(rowHeader);

            return tabela;
        }
```

But my view exibe only:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable
```

My return is HtmlTable, how render this in view?

Comment: It depends on what kind of View you are using. If you are using the Razor-Viewengine (you would be using a lot of @'s in the code), then you should return a `MvcHtmlString` Object instead of a table web-part.

The UI Element you are using there seems to be an aspx UI element, which I have no experience with :D

Comment: And through the window goes my answer if it's WebForms instead of Razor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in a comment, this answer only apply if you are using the Razor ViewEngine.

The problem is that the Razor engine does not know what to do with a `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable`

You should try to build the table using regular HTML tags such as :

```
public static MvcHtmlString Sales(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {


            MvcHtmlString tabela = new MvcHtmlString(@"
<table style=""width: 800px"">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Código</th>
            <th>Unidade</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>QTD</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
");

            return tabela;
        }
```

You could then pass your data and fill the table with your values.

Answer (score 0):

The View is for contains the html output.. Using different "helper" (?) methods won't help you just make your code unmaintainable.